# Why is is this molecule called ketene?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

The marking scheme says that the molecule has both alkene and ketone.
So there is carbon to carbon double bond.ok.check there is alkene.But what about ketone.Ketone has this structure:

[image]

So can we technically say that there is ketone in it?

Answer (score 3):

This molecule is a ketene because it contains the ketene functional group:
[image]

Whilst the ketene appears to contain an alkene and a ketone functional group, which as you have suggested is where its name comes from, its chemistry is notably different from both of its 'constituent groups'.